# How can I read data and put into model in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I need to get some specific data from rest to my model.

Data I get from rest :

> [{"id":595,"name":"TransXChange20210805113332","prosystem_file_id":null,"dataset":16,"creator":113,"editor":113,"created":"2021-08-05T09:45:21.444949Z","edited":"2021-08-05T09:45:27.542152Z","update_from_url":false,"description":"Rozkłady jazdy komunikacji miejskiej ważne od 08.08.2021","file":"https://otwartedane.erzeszow.pl/media/resources/transxchange20210805113332.xml","link":null,"extension":"XML","data_type":"[]","file_name":"transxchange20210805113332.xml","chart_info":null,"map_info":null,"score":4,"public":true,"licence":"other-open","connection_dict":null,"selection_string":null,"db_type":"POSTGRESQL","type":"file","dbview_cache_minutes":1,"preview_base64":null,"gpkg_display_info":null,"archive_to_csv":false},{"id":538,"name":"TransXChange20210513082611","prosystem_file_id":null,"dataset":16,"creator":113,"editor":113,"created":"2021-05-13T06:28:50.233464Z","edited":"2021-07-28T08:52:06.695966Z","update_from_url":false,"description":"Rozkłady jazdy komunikacji miejskiej ważne od 15.05.2021","file":"https://otwartedane.erzeszow.pl/media/resources/transxchange20210513082611.xml","link":null,"extension":"XML","data_type":"[]","file_name":"transxchange20210513082611.xml","chart_info":null,"map_info":null,"score":4,"public":true,"licence":"other-open","connection_dict":null,"selection_string":null,"db_type":"POSTGRESQL","type":"file","dbview_cache_minutes":1,"preview_base64":null,"gpkg_display_info":null,"archive_to_csv":false},{"id":544,"name":"TransXChange20210526143716","prosystem_file_id":null,"dataset":16,"creator":113,"editor":113,"created":"2021-05-26T12:40:42.587492Z","edited":"2021-07-28T08:52:04.417450Z","update_from_url":false,"description":"Rozkłady jazdy komunikacji miejskiej ważne od 01.06.2021","file":"https://otwartedane.erzeszow.pl/media/resources/transxchange20210526143716.xml","link":null,"extension":"XML","data_type":"[]","file_name":"transxchange20210526143716.xml","chart_info":null,"map_info":null,"score":4,"public":true,"licence":"other-open","connection_dict":null,"selection_string":null,"db_type":"POSTGRESQL","type":"file","dbview_cache_minutes":1,"preview_base64":null,"gpkg_display_info":null,"archive_to_csv":false}]

i got it in single line

my code in java :

```
RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
        String soc = builder.build().getForObject("https://otwartedane.erzeszow.pl/v1/datasets/16/resources/", String.class);
        assert soc != null;
        System.out.println(soc);
```

And the problem is I need to put them into model

My model:

```
public class Resource {

private long id;
private String name;
private long prosystem_file_id;
private int dataset;
private int creator;
private int editor;
private LocalDateTime created;
private LocalDateTime edited;
private boolean update_from_url;
private String description;
private String file;
private String link;
private String extension;
private String data_type;
private String file_name;
private String chart_info;
private String map_info;
private int score;
private boolean isPublic;
private String licence;
private String connection_dict;
private String selection_string;
private String db_type;
private String type;
private int dbview_cache_minutes;
private String preview_base64;
private String gpkg_display_info;
private boolean archive_to_csv;
```

All getters and setters are generated.
How can I put them into model for example List?
The problem is I get data like [{resource},{resource},{resource}].

Answer (score 0):

As it states from the [RestTemplate documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-restclient.html)

you can call to the **getForObject** method passing as an argument the desired deserialization class.

Something like:

RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder();

```
Resource soc = builder.build().getForObject("https://otwartedane.erzeszow.pl/v1/datasets/16/resources/", Resource.class);
assert soc != null;
System.out.println(soc);
```

Comment: But the problem is for response i got [{resource},{resource},{resource}]. its like 3 elements array of my model

Comment: Then make a wrapper object that contains a list of resources like `List<Resource> soc` and use that as the response object at your builder.

Comment: List<Resource> soc = builder.build().. what i should put in last argument of .getForObject?? it require class and i cannot put there List<Resource>

Comment: I am not in front of the computer now, but I guess
builder.build().getForObject("https://otwartedane.erzeszow.pl/v1/datasets/16/resources/", Resource[].class) should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer to my question.

I need to assign my call to array of model.

```
Resource[] soc =builder.build().getForObject( URL , Resource[].class );
```